# Bajar todos los archivos en PHP desde una query de MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

He creado una función de php con la intención que mediante una sencilla query de mysql copie archivos que hay en una carpeta a otra según el criterio de fecha.

```
<?php
    function copy_all(){
            $ticket_date_from = $_POST['ticket_date_from'];
            $ticket_date_to = $_POST['ticket_date_to'];

            $combobit="";

            $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE ticket_date BETWEEN '$ticket_date_from' AND '$ticket_date_to'";
            $search_result = filterTable($query);
            $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

            $image_dir = $row['image_dir'];

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
                $copy_to ="../upload/".$image_dir;
                $copy_from ="../renta/".$image_dir;
                copy($copy_to, $copy_from);
                echo "everything copied";
        }
}



function filterTable($query){
     include ('connection.php');
     $filter_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     return $filter_result;
}
?>
```

Para llamar a la función utilizo el atributo onclick en un link html.

```
    <a class="button" href="#" onclick="<?php copy_all()?>">Copiar archivos para la renta</a>
```

Estoy seguro que no es correcto.

Saludos,

Comment: Hola, tienes un problema diferenciando el código del backend con el código del frontend. No puedes hacer el llamado de la función php desde el onclick, deberías utilizar algo como ajax, para que envíe la petición al servidor y ejecute la función.

Comment: En tu php pon algo así como if(isset($_REQUEST["action"])) copy_all(); y en el onclick pon "fichero.php?action=1" Dee sta forma, cuando llames al php con action=1, el if con el isset del REQUEST devolverá true y ejecutará la función.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios. Esta tarde lo probaré ambas. Os comento.

Comment: @track3r esto es lo que he hecho. Pero me pasa lo mismo.

En HTML:
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="<?php "search.php?action=1" ?>">Copiar archivos para la renta</a>

Algo estoy haciendo mal.

Sobre ajax no se como mirarlo. No tengo mucha idea y por mucho que busco en internet, no encuentro nada.

Comment: Así: onclick="search.php?action=1" sin php de por medio.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Tiene que haber algún problema más en el código.

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar el código de tu pregunta con los nuevos cambios para ver que ocurre?

Comment: Este es el código que tengo en un sólo archivo:

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código que tengo en un sólo archivo: (Separado por código php y parte en html5. Muchas gracias track3r

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["action"])){ copy_all();}

function copy_all(){
        $ticket_date_from = $_POST['ticket_date_from'];
        $ticket_date_to = $_POST['ticket_date_to'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE ticket_date BETWEEN '$ticket_date_from' AND '$ticket_date_to'";
            $search_result = filterTable($query);
            $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

            $image_dir = $row['image_dir'];

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
                $copy_to ="../upload/".$image_dir;
                $copy_from ="../renta/".$image_dir;
                copy($copy_to, $copy_from);
                echo "everything copied";
            }
    }

function filterTable($query){
     include ('connection.php');
     $filter_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     return $filter_result;
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div>
 
 <br>
 <div>
 <center>
 
 <form action="search.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="date" name="ticket_date_from" /> A: <input type="date" name="ticket_date_to" /><br><br>
    <form name="excel" method="post">
     <a class="button" href="#" onclick="search.php?action=1">Copiar archivos para la renta</a>
    </form>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>Id.</th>
     <th>Núm. factura</th>
     <th>De</th>
     <th>Fecha factura</th>
     <th>Cantidad</th>
     <th>Tipo</th>
     <th>Seguro</th>
     <th>Dirección</th>
     <th>Fecha ingreso</th>
     <th>Documento</th>
     <th>Impuesto</th>
     <th>Renta</th>
     <th>Descripción</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
       
    if (mysqli_num_rows($search_result)==0){?>
     <tr><td colspan="13"><center><b>No existen registros en la base de datos.</b></center></td></tr>
     <?php
    }else{
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['ticket_index']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ticket_number']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ticket_from']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ticket_date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ticket_ts']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['image_dir']; ?></td>
      <td><a class="boton_eliminar" href="../upload/<?php echo $row['image_dir']; ?>" download >Download</a></td>
     </tr>     
    <?php    
    endwhile;  }?>
    <tr><td colspan="13"><center><b>Registros totales : <?php echo $count_rows;?></b></center></td></tr>    
   </table>
  </form>
 </center>
 </div>
</div>
<?php

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Disculpa que te corrija, pero no añadas tu código como respuesta, en lugar de eso, edita tu pregunta y añade tu nuevo código, reemplazando el anterior o añadiendo al final, como prefieras. En cualquier caso, ¿si llamas desde el navegador search.php?action=1, hace algo? parece que tu código php no funciona.

Comment: Lo siento, no sabía como hacerlo. Borré mucho código php y html que no tenía que ver con esto.

Cuando pulso al link, no hace nada. El código php de copiar de una carpeta a otra me parece correcto. Pero como digo no tengo mucha idea, la idea principal era de comprimir el contenido el zip y bajarlo, pero esta me parecío una idea más sencilla para empezar, y luego una vez funcione. Implementar la otra.

Comment: Prueba algo más sencillo como mostrar un mensaje y comenta el resto de código php, algo así como if(isset($_REQUEST["action"])){ echo "hola mundo";} y el resto comentado, a ver si al menos llegas a ver el mensaje.

Comment: Hola Track, No hace nada.

Comment: Es muy raro, prueba a llamar al fichero php desde el propio navegador, sería algo así como http://dominio/search.php?action=1

Comment: hay si que se ve el echo. Pero al cambiar a if(isset($_REQUEST["action"])){ copy_all();}

No hace nada

Comment: Vale, creo que ya se qué ocurre, llamas al PHP desde un evento onclick y por lo tanto, no posteas el resto de campos que necesitas como el ticket_date_from. Deberías cambiar muchas cosas, por ejemplo, en el action del form llamar a search.php, añadir un campo hidden con el action a 1 y el botón de enviar debería ser un submit.

Comment: Te lo pongo como respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de varias formas, lo ideal sería usando ajax, pero también puedes hacerlo con redirecciones normales, te pongo la parte html con el form que es la que cambia:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="1">
    <input type="date" name="ticket_date_from" /> A: <input type="date" name="ticket_date_to" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Copiar archivos para la renta">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id.</th>
                <th>Núm. factura</th>
                <th>De</th>
                <th>Fecha factura</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Seguro</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Fecha ingreso</th>
                <th>Documento</th>
                <th>Impuesto</th>
                <th>Renta</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <?php

            if (mysqli_num_rows($search_result)==0){?>
                <tr><td colspan="13"><center><b>No existen registros en la base de datos.</b></center></td></tr>
                <?php
            }else{
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ticket_index']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ticket_number']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ticket_from']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ticket_date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ticket_ts']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['image_dir']; ?></td>
                    <td><a class="boton_eliminar" href="../upload/<?php echo $row['image_dir']; ?>" download >Download</a></td>
                </tr>                
            <?php           
            endwhile;   }?>
            <tr><td colspan="13"><center><b>Registros totales : <?php echo $count_rows;?></b></center></td></tr>                
        </table>
    </form>
```

Si te das cuenta, he añadido un campo oculto para definir action y he cambiado el botón por un input de tipo submit. Así envías todos los campos al PHP, porque tal como lo tenías, solo se enviaba el action=1.

De todas formas como te decía, sería mejor hacerlo con AJAX ya que así, no tienes que hacer redirecciones, pero entiendo que hay escenarios en los que AJAX no se puede implementar, por ejemplo, cuando no hay javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Eso no me funcionó. Lo cambie de esta forma y al menos ya funciona el botón.

```
if (isset($_POST['copy_all'])) {

        # While para copiar
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {

            $copy_to = "../upload/".$image_dir;
            $copy_from ="../renta/".$image_dir;
            copy($copy_to, $copy_from);


        }
        echo "everything copied";
```

}

Y en el input

Con eso hace la llamada correctamente.

Ahora tengo este error "Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /volume1/web/recibos/pages/search.php on line 195 " que buscaré como solventarlo.

Muchas gracias Track

Answer (score 0):

Podemos cerrar este post. Lo he resuelto así.

````
if (isset($_POST['copy_all'])) {

            $ticket_date_from = $_POST['ticket_date_from'];
            $ticket_date_to = $_POST['ticket_date_to'];
            $zip = new ZipArchive();


            $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE ticket_date BETWEEN '$ticket_date_from' AND '$ticket_date_to'";
            $search_result = filterTable($query);
            $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

# While para copiar

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):
            //echo var_dump($row);
                $image_dir = $row['image_dir'];             
                $copy_to = '../upload/'.$image_dir;
                $copy_from = '../renta/'.$image_dir;
                copy($copy_to,$copy_from);
                //echo "<H2>Copy files completed!".$image_dir."</H2>";              
            endwhile;
}```
````